# Using images with non-locally stored source in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, canvas

I'm building a web app that is supposed to search for images in Flickr using Flickr api and javascript and then on click on an image in the search result, you should be able to edit the image directly in browser (without saving the image first). I thought using canvas was a good idea, but i cannot edit the images if the images is not locally stored on the computer it seems.
This is a part of what i've got (where the problem lies):

```
var editor = document.getElementById("editor"),
            context = editor.getContext("2d"),
            image = $("<img/>", {
                        src: "cat.jpeg", //i want a source in form of "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/551143684671291392/Nx_lx21L_400x400.jpeg" instead. 
                        load: function() {
                            context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);  
                        }
                    }),
```

So, if i put the src as "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/551143684671291392/Nx_lx21L_400x400.jpeg", the image is not editable.

This is a longer part of my function:

```
(function($){
        //get canvas and context
        var editor = document.getElementById("editor"),
        context = editor.getContext("2d"),
        image = $("<img/>", {
                    src: "cat.jpeg", //get the image src here from flickr... how to get enlargedPhoto. that works
                    load: function() {
                        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);  
                    }
                }),

            //get the toolbar to work
                //toolbar functions
                tools = {

                    //output to <img> 
                    save: function() {

                        var saveDialog = $("<div>").appendTo("body");

                        $("<img/>", {
                            src: editor.toDataURL()
                        }).appendTo(saveDialog);

                        saveDialog.dialog({
                            resizable: false,
                            modal: true,
                            title: "Right-click and choose 'Save Image As'",
                            width: editor.width + 35
                        });
                    },
                    rotate: function(conf) {

                        //save current image before rotating 
                        $("<img/>", { 
                            src: editor.toDataURL(), 
                            load: function() {
                                //rotate canvas
                                context.clearRect(0, 0, editor.width, editor.height);                           
                                context.translate(conf.x, conf.y);
                                context.rotate(conf.r);

                                //redraw saved image
                                context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);  
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    rotateL: function() {
                        var conf = {
                            x: 0,
                            y: editor.height,
                            r: -90 * Math.PI / 180
                        };
                        tools.rotate(conf);
                    },
                    rotateR: function() {
                        var conf = {
                            x: editor.width,
                            y: 0,
                            r: 90 * Math.PI / 180
                        };
                        tools.rotate(conf);
                    },........
```

The HTML:

```
<form class="search-form" method="get" action="/">
        <input id="search-form-q" type="search" placeholder="Type a keyword to search on Flickr" />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <div id="imageEditor"> 
        <section id="editorContainer"> 
            <!--<img id="picture" src="">-->
            <canvas id="editor" width="480px" height="480px"></canvas> <!-- put the img-tag here -->
        </section> 
        <section id="toolbar"> 
            <a id="save" href="#" title="Save">Save</a> 
            <a id="rotateL" href="#" title="Rotate left">Rotate Left</a> 
            <a id="rotateR" href="#" title="Rotate right">Rotate Right</a> 
            <a id="resize" href="#" title="Resize">Resize</a> 
            <a id="greyscale" href="#" title="Convert to grayscale">B&W</a> 
            <a id="sepia" href="#" title="Convert to sepia tone">Sepia</a> 
        </section> 
    </div>
```

I have a function that correctly also returns the src of an image i click on in the search result gallery. The problem is to get this src in the canvas.
How do i do? 
This is not a web app that is going online by the way.

Comment: The issue you are going to most probably run into is the "tainted" canvas. What you could attempt to do is download the image via the src you have into web storage, then create a new `sprite` and set its src to be the web storage location. See if that works

Comment: @Canvas how would you save an unsafe image into webstorage?

Comment: It was an idea, nothing more, that is why I posted a comment not an answer :(

Comment: @Linnea Lindgren since `https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/551143684671291392/` doesn't return the proper cross-origin resources and that it blocks incoming xhr, your only solution would be to use a server proxy.